# Windows Phone 8 ShellTile TargetUri

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-tile, secondary-live-tile

One Quick Question:

I want to navigate to settings(cellular..) from an secondary livetitle.

The Problem is the targetUrl for the Shelltitle(selectedShortcutsMenuControl.TargetUrl) in my app looks like this: "cellular",
and thats not an valid Uri format.

> Exception : "An exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred
>   in System.ni.dll but was not handled in user code"

```
  StandardTileData data = new StandardTileData();
        data.Title = selectedShortcutsMenuControl.Title;
        data.BackgroundImage = myUri;
        ShellTile.Create(new Uri(selectedShortcutsMenuControl.TargetUrl,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), data);
```

Is there a way to fix this or is there a way, to directly navigate to cellular Settings form the livetitle?

```
 <ctl:MenuData x:Key="ShortcutsMenuControlData">
        <ctl:MenuItemData Title="Cellular" TargetUrl="wifi" Image="/Images/Item-fc0d2405-5b0f-4f3d-ba3e-5b93fbfe2c44.png"/>
        <ctl:MenuItemData Title="WiFi" TargetUrl="cellular" Image="/Images/Item-c9f6c2c7-44e1-4079-ad90-e31b8a59333e.png"/>
        <ctl:MenuItemData Title="Airplain Mode" TargetUrl="plaine" Image="/Images/Item-10845593-26f7-485a-bef7-cf9b9b0cf9fe.png"/>
        <ctl:MenuItemData Title="Bluetooth" TargetUrl="bluetooth" Image="/Images/Item-294e2b67-5534-43b3-ae4e-aecf180c9274.png"/>
    </ctl:MenuData>
```

Comment: Where is your code? What is the exact error it's showing? Stack overflow is very structured. Goal - Problem - What you've tried - Errors you've received - Stack Trace - Question. It is formatted this way so that people with similar issues in the future can find your question and any answers it generated. Please reformat your question and I will happily answer it.

Comment: Thank you for making the requested edits. I will look into this problem now and get back to you shortly

Comment: So when you say navigate to settings I am assuming you mean the ones built into the phones actual settings and not something you made in your app correct?

Comment: Yes the phones settings

Comment: what is this: selectedShortcutsMenuControl ?

Comment: A selected item from an ListBox with the data you can see above in MenuItemData

Comment: If the answer below works for you please do not forget to upvote and check mark it as a working answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So inorder to navigate to the native phone settings you need to use the built in URI schemes.

They can be found on [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Specifically for the ones you are asking for the codes are

> ms-settings-airplanemode: Launches the Airplane Mode Settings app.
>
> ms-settings-cellular: Launches the Cellular Settings app.
>
> ms-settings-bluetooth: Launches the Bluetooth Settings app.
>
> ms-settings-wifi: Launches the Wi-Fi Settings app.

replace your target url's with these and it should work

Comment: I tried it navigation inside the app works this way. But creation of the livetitle still is not working: system.ArgumentException

Comment: After doing some research it appears that any live tile created by your app must point to your app. I would suggest creating a page that when navigated to launches the settings. It is an easy hack and shouldnt be noticeable to the user.

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking. Is there an example you can give?

Comment: Okay that is a separate question than what you posted. Please create a new question that is about navigating between pages.